# How to insert date into a mysql database from a jsp page?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, date

I am trying to insert data into MySQL database where one of the column gets the current date.

The code is

```
unit=request.getParameter("unit");
name=request.getParameter("name");
article=request.getParameter("article");
String user=request.getParameter("username");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/newsletter?", "root", "pooja");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();

String query="insert into browse values('"+0+"','"+name+"', '"+NOW()+"', '"+article+"', '"+unit+"', '"+user+"' );";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

The code throws an error at NOW() saying the method is undefined.
Is there any correction I can make in this code itself or is there any other way I can enter the current date into the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `now()` function is a MySQL function, not a Java method call. Therefore it should be part of the SQL text, not a string.

Adding something like `"'" + something + "'"` is correct when `something` is a *Java expression* that returns a string. If `something` contains "foo", then the result is `'foo'` which is a valid SQL string.

But `NOW()` is not a Java expression. It is also not meant to be a literal string in SQL. So you don't need the quotes. Instead, you should have something like `+",NOW(),"+`.

```
String query="insert into browse values('0','"+name+"', NOW(), '"+article+"', '"+unit+"', '"+user+"' );";
```

It is recommended to use a `PreparedStatement` rather than a statement and not embed the strings in that way. And then the `NOW()` would be part of the SQL statement, and the strings would just be replaced by a `?`.

```
String query="insert into browse values('0',?,NOW(),?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setString(2, article);
stmt.setString(3, unit);
stmt.setString(4, user);
int inserted = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks :)
That helped xD

Answer (score 1):

You're indeed calling an undefined Java method `NOW()`, and passing the result of this Java method to the query. What you want is the query to call a **database function** called `NOW()`. So the call to `NOW()` must be part of the query itself:

```
String query = "insert into browse values(?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?)";
```

What are all those question marks, you'll ask. These are placeholders allowing to pass parameters **safely**, using a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). If you persist in using String concatenation to pass parameters, your code will be subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, it will fail as soon as any parameter contains a single quote, and you will fight to insert anything other than strings and numbers (i.e. dates, binary data, etc.). So learn using prepared statements.

Also, `executeQuery()` is used to execute a select query, returning data in a ResultSet. To execute an insert query, you must use `executeUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();`

bear in mind that variable 'now' is of type Date.
you have to modify it to accommodate your DB-> column type

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TIMESTAMP type the date will AUTOMATICALLY be inserted when ever you update the table. This will of course inert time and date, if you just require the date then simply create a new Date object. Also you should really use PreparedStatements to prevent MySQL injection based attacks.